# How do I make my BIOS boot on shimx64.efi file?

Tags: boot-repair

After I did a boot-repair, http://paste.ubuntu.com/5627076/, I get this message:

> Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

I can go to the BIOS but there is no option about that `shimx64.efi` file.

How do I make my BIOS boot on `sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` file?

Comment: is it not booting? actually you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Please boot an Ubuntu emergency disc and post the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`. (You may need to do `sudo apt-get install efibootmgr` first.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can boot into Ubuntu, then you don't have anything to do. (because your BIOS already boots the `sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` file).