# How do I force BIOS to boot to shimx64.efi file when you turn OFF the computer? No dual boot needed

Tags: boot, 18.04, bootloader, reboot, boot-repair

> This will look like a duplicate but I assure you it's not. Unless I simply haven't found the solution yet from the correct post.

When boot-repair says, "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!", how do I do this?

I would think that there should be NO difference between rebooting and turning off and then back on your computer. But in my case, there is.

> Update: Now both restarting and turning off/on do not boot

I looked here:
[How do I make my BIOS boot on shimx64.efi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269766/how-do-i-make-my-bios-boot-on-shimx64-efi-file) (AND MANY OTHER SOURCES BUT TO NO AVAIL)

> I tried, this: - as the previous post suggests. Update: along with reading the links that oldfred posted
>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v

0001 shows that it points to my file. If I restart the computer, it boots (but very slowly), and it seems to be ok as long as I only restart (BUT if I turn off my computer, it will not boot and I am forced to use the USB live ubuntu install, and repeat the boot-repair install process. This is getting incredibly time consuming. Does anyone know how to force the system to always use this? I'm using the LVM setup on ubuntu install. And I believe i'm using EFI since the file is shimx64-efi.

Output from: (using live USB)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0008
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0008,0006,0005,0000,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f3e3baf6-59ba-457d-8dab-9b9770eace6e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003  UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(2089840f7458,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)AMBO
Boot0004  UEFI: IP6 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x0)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(2089840f7458,0)/IPv6([::]:[::]:,0,0)AMBO
Boot0005* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.S.T.1.0.0.0.L.M.0.2.4. .H.N.-.M.1.0.1.M.B.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.S.Q.R.9.J.C.F.0.A.5.0.6.6. . . . . . ......AMBOAMNO........u.K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.T. .1.0.1. .G.2. .P.M.A.P....................A.............................B..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.T. .1.0.1. .G.2. .P.M.A.P......AMBO
Boot0006* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.T.S.S.T.c.o.r.p. .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.N.-.2.0.8.B.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.8.R.9.F.G.6.C.E.0.9.D.0.Z.X. . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot0007  Could not parse device path: No such file or directory
```

I am about to restart my computer again (after reinstalling boot-repair, for the nth time), and am definitely not looking forward to repeating this process again. The reason for my post.

> Update: Still did not reboot, created the following postbin:
> paste.ubuntu.com/p/PF3f4xNDjT
> On reboot, if I hit ESC at the splash screen, I get the following menu:
> [menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEmwJ.jpg) of which none of these options work - they all just bring me straight back to this menu. And not one is this one which boot-repair said I need to boot to: sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
> If I try 'other' and boot to rescue mode, it brings me to this prompt and stops: [initramfs prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtBPX.jpg)
> As of 10/11/2018 10:10PM EST - I'm stuck

Thank you! I really appreciate any guidance here. This is driving me absolutely nuts!

Comment: What brand/model system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Now it doesn't even restart - I'm back online only with the USB live drive. 
I have a samsung NP350E7C-A01US
Specs here: https://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP350E7C-A01US-specs
I'm using the PPA for the boot-repair.
Also, this was a windows machine that had secure boot enabled. I formatted the drive. Disabled secure boot. Running in UEFI mode. Booting EFI, grub shows I'm using EFI.

Comment: Older Samsung threads: Phoenix SecureCore Tiano bios setup and secure boot is greyed out. You need to set a Supervisor Password in the Security tab
Samsung w/ Phoenix Tiano SecureCore
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760102/ubuntu-16-04-error-installing-grub/762267#762267
Samsung Ativ Book 9 Plus UEFI Install  - manual copy of grub to /EFI/Boot
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230919
 Samsung ATIV Book 9 Plus
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203824
Update UEFI/BIOS helped see ports and other issues.
Samsung 900X3E 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176559

Comment: Here is my pastebin url: (just ran now) http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2vWZzH3CX6/

Comment: I checked those links that you posted. They are great links and I even followed some things during install. I'm guessing that I did the installation wrong. But what I do not understand is that why after I install, I simply can not reboot. I am going to try installing again but this time just do the non LVM simple install. I think I was trying to be more complicated than need be. Unless I'm missing something? Maybe my pastebin might show the cure all fix is real simple and I Just don't understand it.

Comment: Prior postbin link was prior to running boot repair - and this next postbin link is after running boot repair again. I'm going to try and restart my computer now. Fingers crossed!! http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PF3f4xNDjT/

Comment: Still does not boot. If I left it, it would stay on the purple ubuntu screen but without the ubuntu logo. I have some more info, I am posting in the original post that might help figure out what to do.

Comment: What video card/chip? You may need nomodeset boot parameter until you install proprietary video driver? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  You also show UEFI grub & system configured for UEFI boot, but an old grub in gpt protective MBR for BIOS boot which will not boot. So do not try BIOS boot.

Comment: hey, ok so none of those options worked. I was forced to reinstall again. This time I noticed a few things. 1. after I deleted all the partitions and tried to install, the install crashed. Found out it was because no EFI partition was installed - and the installer will not create a new one for you if one doesn't exist - which is strange. (known bug in ubuntu installer). Once I created this partition, then on the part of the install that gives a dropdown list asking to select the location to install the boot loader files, I selected the EFI partitioins sdb location. Worked!! Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after much searching I found out that if you try and install ubuntu and it works, but then when you shut down your computer, you can not boot, it may be because 1. You never installed an EFI partition (if you have a EFI system). or 2. During the installation wizard, you didn't select the location of your EFI partition (to be the location to install your boot loader files).

Once I did that it finally worked. Hopefully this helps someone out there!